# Nikon D5100 - how to keep HDR activated after taking a shot?

Tags: hdr, nikon-d5100

I am using the HDR function for the first time lately and what I am finding is that after each image is taken the HDR will disable itself. So you have to go back into the menu and enable it again each time you would like to take a picture.

Is there a way to keep it enabled?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, There is no way to enable in camera HDR for more than a single shot. It will default to "off" each time you take a photo.

It may be possible to assign the front "fn" button in the future but, for now, it will remain a minor inconvenience .

Source: D5100 Owner

*"You must set this to ON for each shot; it resets to OFF after each."*
http://www.kenrockwell.com/nikon/d5100/users-guide/menus-shooting.htm